# How do I fill out an html form using selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

url = http://ptvtelecom.com/
If you follow the url and click the button which says 'combrobar' which should be visible in the middle of the screen, it takes you to a form that needs to be filled out. I was wondering how to fill out the form using selenium.

So ive already tried finding the element by id and by name but it does not work. Any help on how to find the element of the first text box for instance would be greatly aprreaciated.

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
browser = 
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/grsanchez/downloads/chromedriverM', 
options=option)
browser.get('http://ptvtelecom.com/')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
[@id="cobertura"]/div/div[2]/div/div/p/a').click()
```

Here is where it goes wrong

```
name = browser.find_element_by_id('nombre')
name.send_keys('user1')
```

Comment: it is in `<iframe>` and Selenium treads it as separated page and doesn't seach inside `<iframe>`. You have to use `switch_to()`  with this iframe and then you can search `nombre`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

read the comments in the code to understand why your code isn't working.
basically, you're trying to select something that exists inside an iframe.

```py
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incognito")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/grsanchez/downloads/chromedriverM', 
options=option)

browser.get('http://ptvtelecom.com/')

## finding the button that shows the form
btn = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#cobertura .boton-cobertura')

## using js to click it, to avoid getting issues in case the button wasn't visible
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", btn)

## the element you want to select is actually inside an iframe, so we need to switch to it, if we want to select anything
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#popmake-1432 iframe'));

## selecting the name input and sending a string
name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#nombre')
name.send_keys('user1')
```

**PS** to return to the main frame, you can do this :

```py
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you are using `execute_script()` to click a button, you aren't automating a user scenario because users can't click on elements that aren't visible, are covered by other elements, etc.

Answer (score -1):

you need to switch to iframe something like driver.switchTo().frame("a077aa5e");

then use your locators inside the iframe

Comment: this is in java .. not python